# How to write regular expression of head of line, "^", and end of line, "$" in []?

Tags: bash

I am trying to pick out a path, `TARGET_PATH` in `$PATH`. To pick out it, I made

```
grep -q "[:|^]$TARGET_PATH[$|:]"
```

However it does not work.

I am afraid head of line "`^`" and end of line "`$`" may not work in `[]`.

Please tell solution.

Comment: When it is not the first character from the range, `^` keeps its literal value. `$` doesn't have any special meaning inside a character range. The same for `|`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [alternation with `()`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) instead of `[]` ([class of characters or character sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html))

```
grep -q -E "(:|^)\$TARGET_PATH($|:)
```

Comment: Thank you VonC. It looks you uses extension of regular expression by -E. Is  that mean we cannot use ^ nor $ in [] in normal regular expression? I just want to check it. Thank you again.

Comment: @mora you can (depending on your bash and grep version), but you would need to escape the alternation `()`: `\(:|^\)` if you don't use `-E`.

Comment: Note: don't escape the `\$` in front of `TARGET_PATH` if you want to grep the actual value behind this environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

This check doesn't require a `grep`. You can do this in BASH itself:

```
[[ $PATH =~ (^|:)"$TARGET_PATH"(:|$) ]] && echo "found" | echo " not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expressions are cool but in this case you simply don't need them.

Just wrap the string you are searching into (`$PATH`) into a pair of separator characters (`:`). This way you know for sure that the string you are searching for, if it's present in `$PATH`, is always bounded by `:` characters.

A regular search for the string `:$TARGET_PATH:` (no `regex`) is enough to tell you if it's present in `$PATH`:

```
cat ":$PATH:" | grep ":$TARGET_PATH:"
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me !Aha! solution.